# How do I register multiple message mutators in with Structuremap for NServicebus?

Tags: structuremap, nservicebus

I have multiple message mutators I want to add to the NServicebus pipeline. I'm using Structuremap as my IoC container. What's the proper way to register them with both Structuremap and NServicebus?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in the examples.

```
Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<Mutator1>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<Mutator2>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
```